How to get hamburger menu button to display on top of the AppBar using MUI?

why this box get cut when it push to the outside the appbar? i need to show that button half of the appbar.first i thought it was z-index issue. but even i add the box to Drawer, box still hidden when go outside the drawer. I need to show box between the drawer and appbar.but button need to be float.
import * as React from "react";



interface AppBarProps extends MuiAppBarProps {
  open?: boolean;
}

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open",
})<AppBarProps>(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  width: `calc(100% - ${theme.spacing(8)} - 1px)`,
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: DRAWER_WIDTH,
    width: `calc(100% - ${DRAWER_WIDTH}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const AppHeader: React.FC = () => {
  const { navigatorDrawerOpen, onCloseNavigatorDrawer, onOpenNavigatorDrawer } =
    useNavigatorDrawer();
  const { onOpenThemeDrawer } = useThemeDrawer();

  const handleDrawerOpenClose = () => {
    navigatorDrawerOpen ? onCloseNavigatorDrawer() : onOpenNavigatorDrawer();
  };

  return (
    <AppBar
      position="fixed"
      open={navigatorDrawerOpen}
      elevation={0}
      color="inherit"
      variant="outlined"
      sx={{ borderTop: 0 ,overflow:'visible'}}
    >
      <Toolbar>
        
        <IconButton
          edge="start"
          sx={{
            position: "absolute",
              left: 0,
              width: 35,
              height: 35,
              backgroundColor:'skyblue',
              color:'darkblue',
              borderRadius:1,
              zIndex: 5000,
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center" }}
        >
         <Box color="primary" >{// this box is the showing half cut box}
            </Box>
        </IconButton>
            
        
         
        <Box sx={{ ml: 0, flexGrow: 1 }} />
        <IconButton>
          <Settings />
        </IconButton>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default AppHeader;

